# solr performance : différence between long and short query

Tags: performance, solr

I was wondering the better solution between this 2 hypothesis :
3000 short query with 1 condition or 1 query with 3000 conditions

To be more specific :
I search on adresses to get every stores in a city. 
I have every adresses in the city and would have your advice between launching 1 query for each adresse or launching 1 query compiling every adresses with OR condition.

Comment: I strongly recommend an alternative solution where possible, i.e. modelling your data slighly different may probably prove much easier to query.

Can not create an additional field , and you filter on that ?
Depending on the number of addresses you may exceed the max boolean queries supported.
Can you add your initial problem much more in detail ?

Answer (score 0):

I would choose one query with many OR conditions:

1. it will most probably be faster. Faster for sure than running 3000 queries serially, and probably faster than running them in several threads in parallel.
2. the client side code will be simpler too